# Accessing Object Property Values Within an Array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Learning how to access property values.

If I have

```
let object1 = [{name: "HappyHands31"}, {job: "website developer"}, {city: "Chicago"}];
```

How would I console.log just the *value* of the second object? I.e. "website developer".

I know how to console.log the entire key-value pair (or object) by using `.find()`:

```js
let object1 = [{name: "HappyHands31"}, {job: "website developer"}, {city: "Chicago"}];

console.log(object1.find(function(element) {
    return element.hasOwnProperty("job");
}
));
```

But what about just the *value* of this pair?

Comment: Why do you have each property in its own object, instead of a single object like `{name: "HappyHands31", job: "website developer", ...}`?

Comment: @Barmar this was just the way it was presented in a coding challenge...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can acces items in arrays at given position by their index. In javascript indexes of arrays are starting with 0: `myArray[0]`. To access the property of the returned object just use dot-notation: `myArray[0].myProperty`.

```js
let object1 = [{name: "HappyHands31"}, {job: "website developer"}, {city: "Chicago"}];

console.log(object1[1].job);
```

For your given example this can also achieved by appending the property-name (with dot-notation):

```js
let object1 = [{name: "HappyHands31"}, {job: "website developer"}, {city: "Chicago"}];

console.log(object1.find(function(element) {
    return element.hasOwnProperty("job");
}).job);
```

Comment: Sorry I edited the values of "name" and "age" : ) In the second snippet

Answer (score 2):

You can destructure the value:

```js
let object1 = [{name: "HappyHands31"}, {job: "website developer"}, {city: "Chicago"}];
const { job: res } = object1.find(({ job }) => job);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to store somewhere the keys of each object and then access the object the usual way.

```js
    let object1 = [{name: "HappyHands31"}, {job: "website developer"}, {city: "Chicago"}];
    
    for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
       name = Object.keys(object1[i]);
       console.log(object1[i][name])
    }
```

In this case I've assumed that you don't know the name of the key you want to access.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a property access to the end of it.

```js
let object1 = [{name: "HappyHands31"}, {job: "website developer"}, {city: "Chicago"}];

console.log(object1.find(function(element) {
    return element.hasOwnProperty("job");
}).job);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your `object1` is an array of objects, not an object.

Although, there's a way to achieve what you want.

```js
const fun = (arr, prop) => arr.find((obj) => obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))[prop];

const object1 = [{name: 'HappyHands31'}, {job: 'website developer'}, {city: 'Chicago'}];

const property = 'job';

console.log(fun(object1, property));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the object structure is the same in the array, you can flatten that array of objects like this and call it directly as object keys.

```js
let object1 = [{name: "HappyHands31"}, {job: "website developer"}, {city: "Chicago"}];
let flatten = {}
object1.map((currentValue, index) => {
  let key = Object.keys(currentValue)  
  flatten[key] = currentValue[key]
});
console.log(flatten)
console.log(flatten.job)
```