# Cannot Access JSON array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I seem to be having trouble accessing individual elements of a json array. Given this code:

```
json_array=JSON.parse(data);
console.log(json_array);
console.log(json_array.title);
console.log(json_array.requester);
console.log(json_array.none);
```

This is the output:

```
Array(3)
   0: {requester: false}
   1: {title: false}
   2: {none: true}
   length: 3
   [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Obviously I am somehow accessing the individual elements incorrectly. What am I missing? TIA.

Comment: Your json array is an array and not an object, the problem is when you try to access directly a property, you should loop on the elements of your array and then access every property (json_array[0].title)

Comment: you are trying to access an array with dot notation which is how we access object properties,not array items

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Object Property Values Within an Array - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56369661/accessing-object-property-values-within-an-array-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you forget the index when accessing array

```js
console.log(json_array[0].title);
console.log(json_array[1].requester);
console.log(json_array[2].none);
```

Comment: I didn't forget, I didn't know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access `json_array` this way:

```
console.log(json_array);
console.log(json_array[0].title);
console.log(json_array[1].requester);
console.log(json_array[2].none);
```

This is because your `json_array` is an array with three objects, like this:

[
{
"title": ""
},
{
"requester": ""
},
"none": ""
]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) your array into individual variables,which you can use accordingly :

```js
const arr = [
  {title:"title"},
  {requester:"requester"},
  {none:"none"}
]

const [title,requester,none] = arr

console.log(title,requester,none)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
json_array = Object.assign([], json_array).reduce((a, b) 
=> Object.assign(a, b), {});
console.log(json_array);
console.log(json_array.title);
console.log(json_array.requester);
console.log(json_array.none);
```